# How can I get text under the picture in the center of the picture?

Tags: html, css

I want to put text under an image, but it must be horizontal in the center of an image. Not in the center of the page, because I have 3 images and I want to do the same to them. Does anyone know an answer?

This is what I have now. I have played with the margins, but as you see it's not perfectly in the center of an image. I don't know an other way to do it, without playing with the margins.
[image]

This is my code:

```
<section class="people">
        <h1>Our people</h1>
        <div class="putin">
            <img src="images/People/poetin.png" class="img1" alt="poetin">
            <p>Vladimir Putin</p>
        </div>
        <div class="stalin">
            <img src="images/People/stalin.png" class="img1" alt="stalin">
            <p>Joseph Stalin</p>
        </div>
        <div class="peter">
            <img src="images/People/peter.png" class="img1" alt="peter">
            <p>Peter the Great</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And my CSS:

```
.people {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}



.people h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 45px;
}

.putin p,
.stalin p,
.peter p {
    margin-top: 280px;
    margin-left: 17.66%;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.stalin p {
    margin-left: 47%;
}

.peter p {
    margin-left: 74.33%;
}

.img1 {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.img1:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is extremely difficult to position everything using px values and margins etc - and the result tends to be non responsive.

Instead of setting these you could use CSS grid with the layout defined as grid-template-areas.

In this simple snippet the area for the heading takes up the whole of the first row, the areas for the images each take up one third of the second row and the grid is laid out so that the items are justified with 'space-around' which means the free space is distributed evenly between and to the side of the items.

```css
.people {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'H H H' 'I1 I2 I3';
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.people h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 45px;
  grid-area: H;
}

.putin {
  grid-area: I1;
}

.stalin {
  grid-area: I2;
}

.peter {
  grid-area: I3;
}

.putin p,
.stalin p,
.peter p {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.img1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.img1:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<section class="people">
  <h1>Our people</h1>
  <div class="putin">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/250/400" class="img1" alt="poetin">
    <p>Vladimir Putin</p>
  </div>
  <div class="stalin">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/250/400" class="img1" alt="stalin">
    <p>Joseph Stalin</p>
  </div>
  <div class="peter">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/250/400" class="img1" alt="peter">
    <p>Peter the Great</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yeah i get it. This helped me a lot. Thank you very much for your help!